# Drools comparing Sets

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, optaplanner

I'm trying to use Optaplanner to replace myself in scheduling our work planning. 
The system is having a MySQL database containing the necessary information and relationships. For this issue I'll only use the three tables I need:

```
Employees --> Have Skills
Jobs --> Have Skills
Skills
```

In Drools I have the rule

```
rule 'required Skills'
    when
        Job(employee != null, missingSkillCount > 0, $missingSkillCount : missingSkillCount)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10 * $missingSkillCount);
end
```

In `Class Job` I have a function `missingSkillCount()`:

```
    public int getMissingSkillCount() {
        if (this.employee == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (Skill skill : this.reqskills) {
            if(!this.employee.getSkills().contains(skill)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

When I run my program, Optaplanner returns that none of my workers have any skills...

However, when I manually use this function (adapted to accept an Employee as parameter): `public int getMissingSkillCount(Employee employee)`, it **does** return the correct values.

I'm puzzled! I somehow understand that `contains`is checking for the same object, instead of the content of the object. But then I don't understand how to do this efficiently...

Answer (score 0):

1) Are your Jobs in the Drools working memory? I presume they are your `@PlanningEntity` and the instances are in `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty` on your `@PlanningSolution`, so they will be. You can verify this by just matching a rule on `Job()` and doing a `System.out.println`.

2) Try writing the constraint as a ConstraintStream (see docs) and putting a debug breakpoint in the `getMissingSkillCount() > 0` lambda to see what's going on.

3) Temporarily turn on FULL_ASSERT to validate there is no score corruption.

4) Turn on DEBUG and then TRACE logging for optaplanner, to see what's going on inside.

Comment: 1) It seems they are, I DO get a result, however all have a -140hard/0soft score. The output is as expected: a jobnumber, its productname and an assigned employee. However the `getMissingSkillCount` seems to always respond that none of my employees have skills... (What it doesn't when I use the function "manually")
2)I'll look into this and come back
3)No errors show

Comment: 4) Done that. To my untrained eye, it doesn't tell me much.    
  
I presume having some  `not doable, ignoring move` responses doesn't mean anything is wrong.

Comment: Look at the first move in the TRACE log. Do that move manually on an empty solution in your UI and score it. Does it have the same score?

Comment: I've switched to using `ContstraintStream` with the exact same result: no skills for anyone... So for now I'm a bit lost, will re-write entire blocks of code to convince myself of any logical mistakes... Even though the function used works seperately... (But: ConstraintStream is a great addition!)

Comment: Final thought: I remain suspicious of the behaviour of  the `.contains(skill)` part: could this behave differently when Optaplanner is using this instead of a single execution (= manual use of the function)?

Answer (score 0):

Still wondering what makes the difference between letting Optaplanner run `getMissingSkillCount()` and using it "manually".

I fixed it by overriding equals(), that should have been my first clue!